# Mutate top n rows without throwing away the other rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have the following `data.frame` below. I would like to create a new column `w` (for weight). `w` should equal 1 / n for the industries that have the n highest returns for each given date and should equal 0 for the rest of the industries. I can `group_by(date)` and use `top_n(3, wt = return)` to filter the top industries and then `mutate(w = 1/n)`, but how can I `mutate` without throwing away the other industries where `w` = 0?

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 
16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 16556, 16587, 16587, 16587, 
16587, 16587, 16587, 16587, 16587, 16587, 16587, 16617, 16617, 
16617, 16617, 16617, 16617, 16617, 16617, 16617, 16617), class = "Date"), 
    industry = c("Hlth", "Txtls", "BusEq", "Fin", "ElcEq", "Food", 
    "Beer", "Books", "Cnstr", "Carry", "Clths", "Txtls", "Fin", 
    "Games", "Cnstr", "Meals", "Hlth", "Hshld", "Telcm", "Rtail", 
    "Smoke", "Games", "Clths", "Rtail", "Servs", "Meals", "Food", 
    "Hlth", "Beer", "Trans"), return = c(4.89, 4.37, 4.02, 2.99, 
    2.91, 2.03, 2, 1.95, 1.86, 1.75, 4.17, 4.09, 1.33, 1.26, 
    0.42, 0.29, 0.08, -0.11, -0.45, -0.48, 9.59, 6, 5.97, 5.78, 
    5.3, 4.15, 4.04, 3.67, 3.51, 3.27)), row.names = c(NA, -30L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 30 x 3
   date       industry return
   <date>     <chr>     <dbl>
 1 2015-05-01 Hlth       4.89
 2 2015-05-01 Txtls      4.37
 3 2015-05-01 BusEq      4.02
 4 2015-05-01 Fin        2.99
 5 2015-05-01 ElcEq      2.91
 6 2015-05-01 Food       2.03
 7 2015-05-01 Beer       2   
 8 2015-05-01 Books      1.95
 9 2015-05-01 Cnstr      1.86
10 2015-05-01 Carry      1.75
# ... with 20 more rows
```

**EDIT**: How would you handle ties? Suppose there is a tie for third place. The third place weight should be split between 3rd and 4th place (assuming only 2 are tied) with weights of (1/n)/2. The 1st and 2nd place weights stay at 1/n.

**EDIT**: Suppose `n` = 3. The top 3 `A2` values for each `A1` should get a weight `w` of 1/3 *if there are no ties*. If there is a tie for 3rd place (T3), then we have (1st, 2nd, T3, T3) and I would like weights to be 1/3, 1/3, 1/6, 1/6 to maintain a total weight of 1. This is only for 3rd place however. (1st, T2, T2) should have weights of 1/3, 1/3, 1/3. (T1, T1, T2, T2) should have weights of 1/3, 1/3, 1/6, 1/6, etc.

```
structure(list(A1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), A2 = c(1, 3, 3, 
    4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

The output for `df` should be:

```
> df
  A1 A2  w
1  A  1  0 
2  A  3  0.1666
3  A  3  0.1666 
4  A  4  0.3333
5  A  5  0.3333
6  B  6  0
7  B  7  0.3333
8  B  8  0.3333
9  B  8  0.3333
```

Comment: The weight is supposed to be `A2/n` right? Here you have considered it as `1/n`. Also, what does `(T1, T1, T2, T2)` represent?  Ties at first place place and second place ?

Comment: Weight was never A2/n. Numerator was always 1, but previous answers were easy to adjust. Yes, `(T1, T1, T2, T2)` means two ties for 1st and two ties for 2nd place.

Comment: I am confused. In Group `B` top 3 values are 6, 7 and 8 but the weight is assigned to only 7 and 8 values, 6 is ignored. What if we have condition like (T1, T1, T1, T2, T2, T3). Would T2 and T3 values be ignored as well ?

Comment: Yes. For (T1, T1, T1, T2, T2, T3) you would only give 1/3 to T1's. Similarly, suppose we had (T1, T1, T1, T1) all T1 would get 1/4.

Comment: Updated the answer. Hopefully,  it works as per your expectation. The question has evolved a lot from its initial post.

Comment: Yes it does. Question evolved as realized how tricky ties were to handle. I also added ability to give negative weights to bottom ranked A2s following the same technique as your answer. To have both negative and positives together, create `temp_df2` of negatives, `bind_rows(temp_df, temp_df2)` before adding zero observations, and `anti_join(df,.)`. Also note when creating `temp_df2`, `arrange(A1, -A2)`. Thank you so much @Ronak Shah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by `date` then `sort` the `return` variable get the last 3 enteries (top 3) and return `return/n` or else 0.

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 3
df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(w = ifelse(return %in% tail(sort(return), n), return/n, 0))


# date       industry return     w
#   <date>     <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2015-05-01 Hlth       4.89  1.63
# 2 2015-05-01 Txtls      4.37  1.46
# 3 2015-05-01 BusEq      4.02  1.34
# 4 2015-05-01 Fin        2.99  0   
# 5 2015-05-01 ElcEq      2.91  0   
# 6 2015-05-01 Food       2.03  0   
# 7 2015-05-01 Beer       2     0   
#....
```

---

The base R equivalent of the same logic using `ave`

```
ave(df$return, df$date, FUN = function(x) ifelse(x %in% tail(sort(x), n), x/n, 0))
```

---

**EDIT**

As mentioned in comments, in case of ties OP wants to return (1/n)/2 or divide by number of ties we have.

For this I have created a new easier dataframe which makes it easy to understand what is going on.

```
df <- data.frame(A1 = rep(c("A", "B"),c(5, 4)), A2 = 1:9)
df$A2[2] <- 3
```

If we use the current code it gives

```
df %>%
   group_by(A1) %>%
   mutate(w = ifelse(A2 %in% tail(sort(A2), n), A2/n, 0))

  # A tibble: 9 x 3
  # Groups:   A1 [2]
#  A1       A2     w
# <fct> <int> <dbl>
#1 A         1  0   
#2 A         3  1   
#3 A         3  1   
#4 A         4  1.33
#5 A         5  1.67
#6 B         6  0   
#7 B         7  2.33
#8 B         8  2.67
#9 B         9  3
```

which is not what we want. To avoid that, we can group by `A2` again and for only those rows where `w!=0` we divide it by number of occurrences of `A2`.

```
df %>%
  group_by(A1) %>%
  mutate(w = ifelse(A2 %in% tail(sort(A2), n), A2/n, 0)) %>%
  group_by(A2) %>%
  mutate(w1 = ifelse(w != 0, w/n(), w)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A1       A2     w    w1
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A         1  0     0   
#2 A         3  1     0.5 
#3 A         3  1     0.5 
#4 A         4  1.33  1.33
#5 A         5  1.67  1.67
#6 B         6  0     0   
#7 B         7  2.33  2.33
#8 B         8  2.67  2.67
#9 B         9  3     3
```

---

**Another EDIT**

Turns out we just want to divide `w` only for the last group present. Moreover, the sum of all the `w` in each group should sum up to 1. For the updated dataset we can do

```
n <- 3

temp_df <- df %>%
            group_by(A1) %>%
            top_n(n, A2)


 temp_df %>%
     arrange(A1, A2) %>%
     mutate(w = ifelse(A2 == A2[1], 
    (1 - (1/n * sum(A2 != A2[1])))/sum(A2 == A2[1]), 1/n)) %>%
     bind_rows(anti_join(df, temp_df) %>%
                      mutate(w = 0)
    ) %>%
     arrange(A1, A2)


# A1       A2     w
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A         1 0    
#2 A         3 0.167
#3 A         3 0.167
#4 A         4 0.333
#5 A         5 0.333
#6 B         6 0    
#7 B         7 0.333
#8 B         8 0.333
#9 B         8 0.333
```

Let's try another variation where we keep all the values of the group same.

```
df1 = df
df1$A2[6:9] <- 10


 temp_df <- df1 %>%
             group_by(A1) %>%
             top_n(n, A2)


  temp_df %>%
       arrange(A1, A2) %>%
       mutate(w = ifelse(A2 == A2[1], 
      (1 - (1/n * sum(A2 != A2[1])))/sum(A2 == A2[1]), 1/n)) %>%
       bind_rows(anti_join(df1, temp_df) %>%
                      mutate(w = 0)
       ) %>%
       arrange(A1, A2)


#  A1       A2     w
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A         1 0    
#2 A         3 0.167
#3 A         3 0.167
#4 A         4 0.333
#5 A         5 0.333
#6 B        10 0.25 
#7 B        10 0.25 
#8 B        10 0.25 
#9 B        10 0.25
```

The logic is we select the top 3 `A2` values along with their groups using `top_n`. Using `anti_join` we get all the rows which are not in top 3 and assign a fixed weight `w` to them as 0. For the rows which are included in top 3 we get the last group rows and assign them the weight which is remaining after assigning the weights to non-last groups.

Comment: Suppose there is a tie for 3rd place. Rather than 1/n weight, the ties should each get weights of (1/n)/2 if the tie is for 3rd place. First and 2nd should still get (1/n).

Comment: @cpage Updated the answer. Please have a look. I have kept `w` and `w1` column separately to make the difference clear.

Comment: I don't think this works for when two tied for second for first place. Suppose we have first place and then two tied for second (1, T2, T2). In this case I want the three weights to be 1/n, 1/n, 1/n. Only when we have (1, 2, T3, T3) do I want the weights to be 1/n, 1/n, (1/n)/2, (1/n)/2.

Comment: @cpage Please update your question with reproducible example and expected output. You can take dataframe from my edit to show what you need. 8-10 rows should be enough, no need for 30 rows.

Comment: Updated the question with example and more explanation of how to handle ties.

Answer (score 5):

We could create a condition with `ifelse`.  After grouping by 'date', `arrange` the dataset based on the 'date', and 'return' in descending order, then create the 'w' by creating the condition that if the `row_number()` is less than 'n', then divide 'return' by 'n' or else return 0

```
n <- 3
df1 %>%
   group_by(date) %>%
   arrange(date, -return) %>% 
   mutate(w = ifelse(row_number() <= n, return/n, 0))
```

---

If we are using `top_n`, then create the column 'w' in the filtered dataset and join with the original

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  top_n(return, n = 3) %>% 
  mutate(w = return/n()) %>% 
  right_join(df1)  %>% 
  mutate(w = replace_na(w, 0))
```

Comment: How would you handle n lowest returns instead?

Comment: @cpage  Just do `arrange(date, return)` instead`